# Java Synchronized block equivalent in Node

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to limit a method so only one promise at a time can run it.

```
    //Method that should only allow one promise at a time
    async myMethod(obj: MyObj):Promise<MyObj>{
            const canInsert = await this.DbChecks();
            if(canInsert === true){
                return this.insert(obj)
            }
    }
```

I know that this question have been asked and that Node is single thread, but this methods does a db request to check if it should run an insert or not, and if another promise changes the db records at the same time, it makes the checks of the first promise wrong.

Comment: the `await` will halt the code at that line, but if you mean to halt every other promise trying to do the same...

Answer (score 1):

A way to solve this instead of awaiting is to create a queue of promises and once each promise finishes (or times out), the oldest promise from the queue would be popped out (if exists). When a promise is about to be evaluated, then you can just push that promise at the end of the promise queue, so you will achieve the intended behavior of running a single promise at a time.

Comment: I have tried solutions based around this idea, they work but are too invasive, I'm more looking for a solution similar to Java, something along the lines of a out of the box lib that adds a decorator.

Comment: @Litel First, it's not difficult at all to implement this, second, stackoverflow.com is not a place to ask libraries from, we care about what the solution is and not about what fancy out-of-the-box works were done by some fellow developers, third, if you had an out-of-the-box library for this purpose, it would likely do something like the idea suggested here, fourthly, await blocks stuff, your server will lamely wait even for third-party requests to be finished if you go with an await approach. So I suggest that you should understand the solution first, try to implement it.

Comment: @Litel and if you are unhappy with your work, then you could look for third-party libraries, but at that point you will be armed by top-notch knowledge of what happens. Asking for library/plugin/book suggestions is off-topic on this website.

Comment: I known its not difficult, like I said I implemented it. I said it was too invasive, and I would prefer a more user friendly Java like solution so the code stays business oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation of a promise-based mutex:

```
let promises = [];

async function getLock() {
    let resolver;
    let lock = new Promise(done => {
        resolver = () => {
            promises.shift();
            done();
        }
    });
    promises.push(lock);

    // If there's more than one promise in the queue
    // force caller to wait:
    if (promises.length > 1) {
        await promises[0];
    }
        
    return {
        release: resolver
    };
}

module.exports = {
    getLock
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
async myMethod(obj: MyObj):Promise<MyObj>{
    const lock = await getLock(); // prevent other code from executing this

    const canInsert = await this.DbChecks();
    if(canInsert === true){
        return this.insert(obj)
    }

    lock.release();
}
```

The idea is actually quite simple. Each call to `getLock()` will insert it's own promise to a queue (the promises array) and this queue manages the order the calls are scheduled.

The promises in the queue only return if there is only one promise in the queue. So the first function to call it gets a promise but if another function calls it it will have to wait. Calling `lock.release()` removes itself from the queue allowing the next call to return a promise.

This is a very simple mutex implementation that has only one mutex globally. You can modify it to support multiple mutex by using some sort of ID to separate the promise queue (the promises array) for each mutex:

```
let promises = {};
```

then:

```
async function getLock(id) { ...
```

and create the promises array on demand:

```
if (promises[id] === undefined) {
    promises[id] = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Try to not limit your function.

I know that this could be useful in some situations, but if you deploy the code to production and there is more than one instance of your app running, then you will need more than a queue in a variable. This usually isn't a problem because a lot of databases are ACID compliant (it's safe to run multiple actions simultaneously) so if the one you are using is compliant, then hopefully you don't need to worry about this.

#### 2. Implement a queue/limit mechanism

Like I said in the the 1st way, this wouldn't have much of an effect depending on the way you deployed the code. This still is a good idea if you want to reduce load or make concurrency easier, and I think the best way is in slebetman's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68537409/12426277.